# How to draw the FA or NFA of b*(ab)*a*

Tags: finite-automata

I'm learning the formal language and the theory of computation,
and new in draw finite automata.
So I want to ask how to draw FA or NFA for:

b*(ab) * a*

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Now I try to draw the NFA like: http://imgur.com/TrFhXsb , but the first state is epsilon, how to convert it to FA?

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737493/how-to-convert-this-nfa-to-dfa. That question should be able to help you.

Comment: So I also want to know if the first state to second state is epsilon, how to fill in the states table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplified automaton is this one:

[image]

Where 1 is the starting state and all states are accepting states. It needs to be completed with a "Trash" state where all missing transitions will go.

Answer (score -1):

Here I just drew a simple understandable NFA To demonstrate the solution for the given question

Image 1

[image: 1]